# Recovering from Consul "No Cluster leader" state

Tags: mesos, consul

I have:

- one mesos-master in which I configured a consul server;
- one mesos-slave in which I configure consul client, and;
- one bootstrap server for consul.

When I hit start I am seeing the following error:

> 2016/04/21 19:31:31 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: rpc error: No cluster leader
>       2016/04/21 19:31:44 [ERR] agent: coordinate update error: rpc error: No cluster leader

How do I recover from this state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you look at the [Consul docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/day-2-operations/outage) ?

It looks like you have performed a ungraceful stop and now need to clean your `raft/peers.json` file by removing all entries there to perform an outage recovery. See the above link for more details.

Comment: Looks like this is a dead link now... I think the new version is https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/day-2-operations/outage?

Answer (score 9):

As of Consul 0.7 things work differently from Keyan P's answer. `raft/peers.json` (in the Consul data dir) has become a manual recovery mechanism. It doesn't exist unless you create it, and then when Consul starts it loads the file and deletes it from the filesystem so it won't be read on future starts. There are instructions in `raft/peers.info`. Note that if you delete `raft/peers.info` it won't read `raft/peers.json` but it will delete it anyway, and it will recreate `raft/peers.info`. The log will indicate when it's reading and deleting the file separately.

Assuming you've already tried the `bootstrap` or `bootstrap_expect` settings, that file might help. The [Outage Recovery guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/day-2-operations/outage) in Keyan P's answer is a helpful link. You create `raft/peers.json` in the data dir and start Consul, and the log should indicate that it's reading/deleting the file and then it should say something like "cluster leadership acquired". The file contents are:

```
[ { "id": "<node-id>", "address": "<node-ip>:8300", "non_voter": false } ]
```

where `<node-id>` can be found in the `node-id` file in the data dir.

Answer (score 2):

I will update what I did:
Little Background: We scaled down the AWS Autoscaling so lost the leader. But we had one server still running but without any leader.

What I did was:

1. I scaled up to 3 servers(don't make 2-4)
2. stopped consul in all 3 servers.`sudo service consul stop`(you can do status/stop/start)
3. created peers.json file and put it in old server(/opt/consul/data/raft)
4. start the 3 servers (peers.json should be placed on 1 server only)
5. For other 2 servers join it to leader using `consul join 10.201.8.XXX`
6. check peers are connected to leader using `consul operator raft list-peers`

Sample peers.json file

```
[
  {
    "id": "306efa34-1c9c-acff-1226-538vvvvvv",
    "address": "10.201.n.vvv:8300",
    "non_voter": false
  },
  {
    "id": "dbeeffce-c93e-8678-de97-b7",
    "address": "10.201.X.XXX:8300",
    "non_voter": false
  },
  {
    "id": "62d77513-e016-946b-e9bf-0149",
    "address": "10.201.X.XXX:8300",
    "non_voter": false
  }
]
```

These id you can get from each server in /opt/consul/data/

```
[root@ip-10-20 data]# ls
checkpoint-signature  node-id  raft  serf
[root@ip-10-1 data]# cat node-id
```

Some useful commands:

```
consul members
curl http://ip:8500/v1/status/peers
curl http://ip:8500/v1/status/leader
consul operator raft list-peers
cd opt/consul/data/raft/
consul info
sudo service consul status
consul catalog services
```

Answer (score 1):

If u got raft version more than 2:

`[
  {
    "id": "e3a30829-9849-bad7-32bc-11be85a49200",
    "address": "10.88.0.59:8300",
    "non_voter": false
  },
  {
    "id": "326d7d5c-1c78-7d38-a306-e65988d5e9a3",
    "address": "10.88.0.45:8300",
    "non_voter": false
  },
  {
    "id": "a8d60750-4b33-99d7-1185-b3c6d7458d4f",
    "address": "10.233.103.119",
    "non_voter": false
  }
]`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had 2 worker nodes in the k8s cluster, after adding another node the consul servers could elect a master and everything is up and running.

Answer (score -2):

You may also ensure that bootstrap parameter is set in your Consul configuration file `config.json` on the first node:

```
# /etc/consul/config.json
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    ...
}
```

or start the consul agent with the `-bootstrap=1` option as described in the official [Failure of a single server cluster](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/recovery-outage) Consul documentation.